# Run several sql scripts and spool output in ubuntu

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, ubuntu

Im a teaching assistant for a databases course in my university. I have the assignments of all of the students. Each assignment has a file 'queries.sql'. Is there a way to run all these scripts at once and spool the output to its own output file in ubuntu?

Comment: You mean a shell script that loops over the .sql files (if they have the same name, are they in different directories?) and for each one, calls SQL\*Plus to run the script, and redirects (or spools) the output to a unique destination? Or one that create a combined .sql file that changes the spool location for each script before it runs it?

Comment: They are in different directories (according to the student name) but all of them have the same name. I would like it to spool the output to a unique destination/name. Im really not familiar with bash scripting.

Answer (score 0):

you need look into [SQLPLus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm) documentation 
see for SqlPlus command line parameters `serveroutput` and `spool`

2 exampleы of run sql files from sqplus

start.sql - the file that start student1.sql and student2.sql

student1.sql - file for student 1

student2.sql - file for student 2

to run the example you need run SqlPlus `sqlplus myuser/mypassword@myserver @start.sql`

the script files below

1 example `start.sql` spools each file into separate output

```
set serveroutput on

spool students1.out
@@.\student1.sql
spool students2.out
@@.\student2.sql

spool off
set serveroutput off
exit
```

2nd example `start.sql` spool all files into one output file

```
set serveroutput on
spool students.out


@@.\student1.sql
@@.\student2.sql

spool off
set serveroutput off
exit
```

students files - just simple "hello I'm student" scripts

`student1.sql`

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('hello I`m student1');
end;
/
```

`student1.sq2`

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('hello I`m student1');
end;
/
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the output from each script in a separate file.

Comment: updated, added 2 samples - spool into separate files and spool into one file